# Config mongo as connection string in grails 2.3.4

Tags: mongodb, grails

I'm using grails 2.3.4 and I need to integrate mongo via connection string.
Its working with below config,

```
grails {            
        mongo {
            host="localhost"
            port=27017
            databaseName="test"
        }
    }
```

But when I try with url, I'm getting connection error.

```
   grails {         
        mongo {
            url="mongodb://localhost/test"
        }
    }
```

The mongo version is 2.0.1
What's wrong with the config I did?

Thanks in advance

Comment: you are missing the port number on the second one

Comment: It's advised, it will take default port 27017, if it was not given.
I also tried with port number. Doesn't help.

Answer (score 0):

Its resolved. Gave connectionString instead url.

```
grails {         
    mongo {
        connectionString="mongodb://localhost/test"
    }
}
```

> Note: It takes application name as database name